# openrouteservice.org API

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

when using openrouteservice...

and adapting the suggested url example on their [wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService)...

if running the following url in the browser...

http://openrouteservice.org/index.php?start=7.0892567,50.7265543&end=7.0986258,50.7323634&lat=50.72905&lon=7.09574&zoom=15&pref=Fastest&lang=en

I get a relevant route...

But I would like to remove dependence on the browser so that I would be able to programmatically download the XML, route profile and GPX (available on the left hand side) using `R`, by providing any given lat/lon combination and adding in the approriate paramters into the URL.

My thoughts were to use the `httr` package with the `GET` or `POST` command as I do not want to use `RSelenium`.

Using Google Chrome's inspect elements doesn't seem to lead to a clear URL...so I'm not too sure how to start going about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it (Chrome) does… Look for `http://openrouteservice.org/php/OpenLSRS_DetermineRoute.php`

```
library(httr)

params <- list(Start="7.0892567,50.7265543",
               End="7.0986258,50.7323634",
               Via="",
               lang="en",
               distunit="KM",
               routepref="Fastest",
               avoidAreas="",
               useTMC="",
               noMotorways="false",
               noTollways="false",
               instructions="true",
               `_`="")

resp <- POST("http://openrouteservice.org/php/OpenLSRS_DetermineRoute.php",
             body=params, encode="form")

content(resp)

## <xls:XLS xmlns:xls="http://www.opengis.net/xls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/xls http://schemas.opengis.net/ols/1.1.0/RouteService.xsd">
##   <xls:ResponseHeader xsi:type="xls:ResponseHeaderType"/>
##   <xls:Response xsi:type="xls:ResponseType" requestID="123456789" version="1.1" numberOfResponses="1">
##     <xls:DetermineRouteResponse xsi:type="xls:DetermineRouteResponseType">
##       <xls:RouteSummary>
##         <xls:TotalTime>PT2M39S</xls:TotalTime>
##         <xls:TotalDistance uom="KM" value="2.2"/>
##         <xls:BoundingBox srsName="EPSG:4326">
##           <gml:pos>7.0892519 50.7254372</gml:pos>
##           <gml:pos>7.1039336 50.7323788</gml:pos>
##         </xls:BoundingBox>
##       </xls:RouteSummary>
##       <xls:RouteGeometry>
##         <gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:4326">
##           <gml:pos>7.0892567 50.7265543</gml:pos>
##           <gml:pos>7.089251870496228 50.72654506565571</gml:pos>
## ....
```

Comment: I'm not sure if its just me, but does this solution still work?

Comment: The service is at least til available. This link [http://openrouteservice.org/php/OpenLSRS_DetermineRoute.php?Start=7.0892567,50.7265543&End=End=7.0986258,50.7323634&Via&lang=en&distunit=KM&routepref=Fastest&avoidAreas&useTMC&noMotorways=false&instructions=true](http://openrouteservice.org/php/OpenLSRS_DetermineRoute.php?Start=7.0892567,50.7265543&End=End=7.0986258,50.7323634&Via&lang=en&distunit=KM&routepref=Fastest&avoidAreas&useTMC&noMotorways=false&instructions=true) does still work (Shows an error in your browser atleast in Chrome). Test it using something like Postman REST Client.

Comment: I just re-ran the code w/o change and it returned the same route answer.

Comment: not exactly our problem (this is the problem with "hacks") - this appears to be the new format for the URL which was extremely superficially easy to figure out http://openrouteservice.org/?pos=-70.78291390000011%2C43.067816400000225&zoom=10&layer=B000FTTTTTTTTTT&routeOpt=Fastest&avHigh=false&avToll=false&avArea=&wp=-70.80262684667518%2C43.25959031288502%2C-70.78291390000011%2C43.0678164000002&lang=en&routeLang=en&distUnit=m&version=undefined&avUnpaved=false&avFerry=false&value_length=15&value_height=4&value_weight=7&value_width=4&surface=cobblestone:flattened&incline=6&slopedCurb=0.06

Answer (score 1):

[openrouteservice](https://openrouteservice.org) API can now be easily interfaced from R with the help of [openrouteservice](https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice-r) package. No need to fiddle with constructing the queries manually anymore! Consider the following example, and have a look the package [vignette](https://giscience.github.io/openrouteservice-r/articles/openrouteservice.html) for an overview of the offered functionality.

```
library(openrouteservice)

# one-time API key set-up
# ors_api_key("<your-api-key>")

# query for coordinates
locations <- lapply(c("Heidelberg", "Kraków"), ors_geocode)
coordinates <- lapply(locations, function(x) x$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates)

# find route 
route <- ors_directions(coordinates, format="geojson")

# route length in kilometres and duration in hours
unlist(route$features[[1]]$properties$summary) / c(1000, 3600)
##    distance    duration
## 1051.861300    9.205167

# draw on map using leaflet
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addGeoJSON(route, fill=FALSE) %>%
  fitBBox(route$bbox)
```

[image]